# MediaCodec - intentionally adding silence to the audio track

Tags: android, audio, android-mediacodec

I've managed to combine multiple videos with audio tracks, but then I realized that if I combine multiple videos with one of them not having an audio track, I have to add silence to the combined audio track.

So, how do I go about doing it? Should I encode a ByteBuffer filled with 0s with timestamps for silence?

Answer (score 0):

> So, how do I go about doing it? Should I encode a ByteBuffer filled with 0s with timestamps for silence?

Essentially yes. I am using the function below to encode silence at a certain presentation time.
For the length of your video with no audio, you should be encoding silence at a regular interval. I determined that the interval should match the audio before it. So in my case, the period between audio presentation times of my first video was 21333 us.

Using that info I started encoding silence:
from the last presentation time of the first video's audio + 21333,
 at intervals of 21333 until I encoded enough silence to last the full video

I am still trying to figure out how to use a video with no audio (as the first video) followed by a video with audio. I will update my answer if I figure it out.

```
private byte[] zerodArray = new byte[2048];// Used to encode silent audio... Not really sure how big this should be ......

private void encodeSilenceForFrame(long presentationTime){
    //mAudioEncoder is the audio encoder you are using to combine the other videos' audio.
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000;
    int encoderInputBufferIndex = mAudioEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
    if (encoderInputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "no audio encoder input buffer");
    }
    if (VERBOSE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "audio encoder: returned input buffer: " + encoderInputBufferIndex);
    }
    ByteBuffer encoderInputBuffer = mAudioEncoder.getInputBuffer(encoderInputBufferIndex);
    encoderInputBuffer.position(0);
    encoderInputBuffer.put(zerodArray);
    Log.d(TAG, "audio silence: pending buffer for time " + presentationTime);


    mAudioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(
            encoderInputBufferIndex,
            0,
            zerodArray.length,
            presentationTime,0);

}
```